# Como exibir as primeiras linhas da saida de um comando no windows?

Tags: windows

O que seria equivalente ao comando `primeiro comando | head -5` no sistema operacional linux dentro do windows?

Eu preciso exibir no console somente as primeiras 5 linhas do comando `git log`.